# How to make Dired sort on special characters in the beginning of file or folder names?

Tags: window, dired

In Windows File Explorer (FE) I can give a file or folder a name with a special character as the first character, and thereby make them move on top when sorting the files alphabetically. For instance, in FE  the folder named `.baby` will be sorted above both of the folders `atom` and `car`, while in Dired `.baby` will be sorted between those two other folders, as if the character `.` is not seen by Dired.

How can I make Dired sort on special characters?

Comment: I have the same problem, it doesn't matter if the special character is in the beginning of the file name, or in between, Dired skips/ignores the special characters for sorting. So for example `a.a` will be sorted before `ab`. I also would like to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize `ls-lisp-UCA-like-collation` variable:

> `ls-lisp-UCA-like-collation` is a variable defined in `ls-lisp.el`.
>
> Non-nil means force ls-lisp use a collation order compatible with UCA.
>
> UCA is the Unicode Collation Algorithm.  GNU/Linux systems automatically
>   follow it in their string-collation routines if the locale specifies
>   UTF-8 as its codeset.  On MS-Windows, customize this option to a non-nil
>   value to get similar behavior.
>
> When this option is non-nil, and `ls-lisp-use-string-collate` is also
>   non-nil, the collation order produced on MS-Windows will ignore
>   punctuation and symbol characters, which will, for example, place
>   `.foo` near `foo`.  See the documentation of `string-collate-lessp`
>   and `w32-collate-ignore-punctuation` for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But where on my computer do I find this ls-lisp-UCA-like-collation variable?

Comment: It's in your Emacs. `C-h v ls-lisp-UCA-like-collation` will give you documentation and with `M-x customize-variable <RET> ls-lisp-UCA-like-collation` you can customize it.

Comment: You wrote : "When this option is non-nil, and ls-lisp-use-string-collate is ALSO non-nil", so there are two places where options are to be customized?  I found where to customize the lisp variable, but where to customize the other?

Comment: `ls-lisp-use-string-collate` it's just another variable. It can be customized via `M-x customize-variable <RET> ls-lisp-use-string-collate`

Comment: It worked! I just had to re-start emacs. Thanks :)